# AWS Credential Error in Runtime using JavaScript AWS SDK v2.784.0

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk-nodejs, aws-credentials

I'm encountering an AWS credential error when using the `aws-sdk` version 2.784.0 in a JavaScript runtime environment. The error message is as follows:

```
Error: Missing credentials in config, if using AWS_CONFIG_FILE, set AWS_SDK_LOAD_CONFIG=1 Missing credentials in config, if using AWS_CONFIG_FILE, set AWS_SDK_LOAD_CONFIG=1
```

**Infrastructure:** My code is deployed to an EC2 instance, and it's expected to load credentials from an IAM Role and no accessKeyId, secretAccessKey and sessionToken are passed.

**Steps to Reproduce:**
It's important to note that this issue is not consistently reproducible, but here are the steps that trigger the problem:

1. Create an S3 stream to upload a file using the `s3:upload` API.
2. Continuously write content to the stream for approximately 30-40 minutes.
3. Attempt to close the stream to create a file on S3, which occasionally throws the error mentioned above.

Strangely, on subsequent retry attempts, the operation works fine without any credential issues.

I appreciate any insights or guidance on how to resolve this intermittent AWS credential error when using the `aws-sdk` for JavaScript.